# how to Import phpmyadmin in joomla database csv file

Tags: database, csv, import, joomla

Also Format-Specific Options:
Columns separated with, Columns enclosed with, Columns escaped with, Lines terminated with.

When I import csv file in phpmyadmin then following this error.

```
Error
SQL query:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database_name`.`TABLE 1` (`COL 1` varchar(26), `COL 2` varchar(48), `COL 3` varchar(2524), `COL 4` varchar(2055), `COL 5` varchar(86874), `COL 6` varchar(11014), `COL 7` varchar(367), `COL 8` varchar(847), `COL 9` varchar(47859), `COL 10` varchar(329), `COL 11` varchar(3470), `COL 12` varchar(3709), `COL 13` varchar(136), `COL 14` varchar(2289), `COL 15` varchar(202), `COL 16` varchar(2848), `COL 17` varchar(150), `COL 18` varchar(1371), `COL 19` varchar(1379), `COL 20` varchar(667), `COL 21` varchar(3), `COL 22` varchar(19), `COL 23` varchar(647), `COL 24` varchar(648), `COL 25` varchar(1), `COL 26` varchar(4), `COL 27` varchar(81), `COL 28` varchar(1), `COL 29` varchar(19), `COL 30` varchar(19), `COL 31` int(1), `COL 32` varchar(19), `COL 33` varchar(19), `COL 34` int(1), `COL 35` varchar(4), `COL 36` int(1), `COL 37` int(1), `COL 38` int(1), `COL 39` varchar(10), `COL 40` varchar(10), `COL 41` varchar(10), `COL 42` varchar(10), `COL 43` varchar(10), `COL[...]

MySQL said: Documentation

#1118 - Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs
```

[image]

Comment: Is this an actual Joomla database you exported from somewhere? It doesn't make senes to import otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a table with the same number of columns in your CSV file. Make all of the columns with large VARCHAR lengths (varchar(2055), etc) type LONG TEXT (or BLOB if they are in fact blobs). You can change they types back to VARCHAR later if you need.

After creating the new, empty table, click the "Import" button on the main page for the table and import the CSV file into the newly created table.

However, if possible you may be better off exporting your Joomla tables as SQL instead of CSV (Using mysqldump or phpMyAdmin).